# Xpath doesn't show all elements inside tag

Tags: python, lxml

I need to find the tag with all elements inside tag, 
xpath finds this tag but show only some part

BeautifulSoup can't parse this html entirely (not exactly this example
because it is little part of whole html)

```
text="<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"issuer-profile-export-quote\" name=\"em\" value=\"175924\" />"

tree = html.fromstring(text)
items_lxml=tree.xpath('//input[@name="em"]')
items_lxml
```

I need to extract the attribute `value=\"175924\"`

But xpath returns only:

```
[InputElement 1ab4da4eb88 name=em type=hidden]
```

Comment: Chrome has a copy element identifier in dev tools, could be helpful.

Comment: Please show the relevant snippet of the html/xml and try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is one that can be parsed.

Comment: Hi Марина, welcome to Stack Overflow! The SO community loves to help, given the question is properly posted with the all the necessary details. In your case we would need, atleast the link of the webpage you're trying to scrape and some bare amount of code that you've come up with.

> I need to extract the attribute value=\"175924\".. How can we possibly know what is attribute value 175924, if we don't even know the webpage?!

Comment: Try using `//input/@value` as your xpath expression and see if that works.

Comment: Try doing items_xml.value